# Caddy rewrite with proxy

Tags: reactjs, docker, proxy, reverse-proxy, caddy

I'm trying to host a react app with Caddy, where a few endpoints redirect to other docker containers, and the rest rewrite to the base url (aka the index.html file for the react app).

But the proxy isn't forwarding to the other containers, it just shows the react app.

How can I make it show the api pages instead of the react app?

```
example.com {
    gzip    
    root /app/frontend

    proxy /staticfiles django:8000 {
        transparent
    }
    proxy /api django:8000 {
        transparent
    }

    proxy /admin django:8000 {
        transparent
    }

    rewrite {
        to .* /index.html
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it could be a directive ordering issue, or the lack of ordering. Like for example if `rewrite` happens before `proxy`, i'm not sure. You could try rewrite the config to something that uses the fact that caddy site addresses are matched longest first. So something like this:

```
example.com {
    gzip    
    root /app/frontend

    rewrite {
        to .* /index.html
    }
}
example.com/staticfiles example.com/api example.com/admin {
    proxy / django:8000 {
        transparent
    }
}
```

Comment: When I try that I'm getting an ssl cert error, and when I ignore that error I get too many redirects.

Comment: Hmm that sounds strange. Done any other changes? I would try to add more log and use `curl -v` to see what is going on